# Content Security Policy and REST API call - how does it work?

Tags: javascript, rest, content-security-policy

I am finding it difficult to understand an error thrown by my app when trying to invoke a REST API.

My app, a pure HTML, JavaScript based using jQuery, is running in Jetty server. The server has implemented `Content-Security-Policy`:

```
Custom HTTP headers to be added to our responses: Content-Security-Policy: 
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self'; 
img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; base-uri 'self'; 
frame-ancestors 'self'; font-src 'self';frame-src 'self'|X-Frame-Options: 
SAMEORIGIN|X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff|X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block|
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin|Feature-Policy: 'none'|Strict-Transport-Security: 
max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

I understand this part. Anyone trying to access my app has to adhere to these restrictions.

However, the JavaScript code in my app tries to call a Spring Boot REST API running on same Linux VM (http://localhost:8080/... or http://server-host-name:8080/...). When doing so, I get `Content Security Policy violated when accessing http://localhost:8080...: content-src 'self'`.This confuses me. Trying to access my app in Jetty without adhering to the security policy should raise error. But why would it throw an error when app in Jetty it is calling a Spring Boot API which doesn't have any such restriction?

Do I need to relax the Content Security Policy restriction on Jetty server? If so, why?

**Summary**:
REST API: Spring Boot HTTP API running on same Linux VM
Jetty Server: CSP restriction as mentioned above
JavaScript app in Jetty: Calling Spring Boot API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Briefly*: you have to add `http://localhost:8080` to the `default-src` directive.

*Tl; DR;*: the `'self'` token is insidious, because you intuitively endow him with powers that he fails to fulfill.

Browsers substisute the `'self'` token with the "tuple origin" (*scheme* + *host_name* + *port_number*) of the page URL from the browser's address bar, and then they add some CSP-specific magic:

- allow `ws:` + *host_name* + ws_standard_port
- allow upgrade `ws:` to `wss:` and `http:` to `https:` in CSP3-browsers

So, what do we have:

1. Your app uses fetch to access Spring Boot REST API which should be covered by missing `connect-src` directive, therefore browser uses `default-src` as fallback.
2. Browser transform `default-src 'self'` to the `default-src http://your_domain.com:80` or `default-src https://your_domain.com:443` (depending on how you load the page).

As you can see both of these do not allow `http://localhost:8080`. Although actually `localhost` is an alias of the `your_domain.com`, but CSP does not know this, and just blocking because of mismatch *host_name* + *port_number*.

But if you will load app with the `http://localhost:8080/your_app_path` url, fetch to REST API will be allowed because covered by `'self'`

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I was understanding this concept entirely wrongly. Thanks for clarifying