# How to understand the Content-Security-Policy (CSP) rules by the popular websites?

Tags: facebook, security, twitter, http-headers, content-security-policy

Recently I was doing some research on CSP, and I found some weird declarations of CSP from dominant websites.

For Facebook, after logging in, the CSP is like:

```
default-src * data: blob: 'self';
script-src *.facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' blob: data: 'self';
style-src data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' *;
connect-src *.facebook.com facebook.com *.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net wss://*.facebook.com:* wss://*.whatsapp.com:* attachment.fbsbx.com ws://localhost:* blob: *.cdninstagram.com 'self';
block-all-mixed-content;
upgrade-insecure-requests;
```

What confused me is that `default-src` uses an asteroid(*) and then follows with other stricter rules ('self'):

```
default-src * data: blob: 'self';
```

In my recent studies, the asteroid syntax is usually not suggested which will make your website insecure. And I cannot figure out what is the final effect of this rule, if `self` always overrides `*`, then why leave a redundant `*`.

As for Twitter, their CSP is like:

```
connect-src 'self' blob: https://*.giphy.com https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv https://*.twimg.com https://api.twitter.com https://api-stream.twitter.com https://ads-api.twitter.com https://aa.twitter.com https://caps.twitter.com https://media.riffsy.com https://pay.twitter.com https://sentry.io https://ton.twitter.com https://twitter.com https://upload.twitter.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://app.link https://api2.branch.io https://bnc.lt wss://*.pscp.tv https://vmap.snappytv.com https://vmapstage.snappytv.com https://vmaprel.snappytv.com https://vmap.grabyo.com https://dhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://pdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net ; 
default-src 'self'; 
form-action 'self' https://twitter.com https://*.twitter.com; 
font-src 'self' https://*.twimg.com; 
frame-src 'self' https://twitter.com https://mobile.twitter.com https://pay.twitter.com https://cards-frame.twitter.com   https://accounts.google.com/; 
img-src 'self' blob: data: https://*.cdn.twitter.com https://ton.twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://analytics.twitter.com https://cm.g.doubleclick.net https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.periscope.tv https://www.pscp.tv https://media.riffsy.com https://*.giphy.com https://*.pscp.tv https://*.periscope.tv https://prod-periscope-profile.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net https://scontent-sea1-1.xx.fbcdn.net https://*.googleusercontent.com https://imgix.revue.co; 
manifest-src 'self'; 
media-src 'self' blob: https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://*.vine.co https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv https://*.giphy.com https://media.riffsy.com https://dhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://pdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net; 
object-src 'none'; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.twimg.com    https://www.google-analytics.com https://twitter.com https://app.link https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js  'nonce-ODdiNzNlNGYtNjFmNS00ZmYxLWE0ZjctODViNTU5YmI4Zjk5'; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://accounts.google.com/gsi/style https://*.twimg.com; 
worker-src 'self' blob:; 
report-uri https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=O5RXE%3D%3D%3D&ro=false
```

what confused me is the `script-src`:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.twimg.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://twitter.com https://app.link https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/appleauth/static/jsapi/appleid/1/en_US/appleid.auth.js  'nonce-ODdiNzNlNGYtNjFmNS00ZmYxLWE0ZjctODViNTU5YmI4Zjk5';
```

I thought `nonce` is designed to prevent the usage of `unsafe-inline`, but in the above directive, both exist. Again, my question is if the latter overrides the former, why leave a redundant `unsafe-inline`.

Comment: For Twitter's question the MDN by Mozilla said: Specifying nonce makes a modern browser ignore 'unsafe-inline' which could still be set for older browsers without nonce support.

Also, CSP Evaluator by Google suggests "Consider adding 'unsafe-inline' (ignored by browsers supporting nonces/hashes) to be backward compatible with older browsers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> default-src * data: blob: 'self';
> ```
>
> In my recent studies, the asteroid syntax is usually not suggested which will make your website insecure.

That's generally yes, but most potentially dangerous for XSS the `script-src` and `connect-src` directives have their own whitelist of sources without `*`.
For the remaining fallback-directives, the asterisk `*` is not a dangerous source (maybe except `object-src`), on the contrary, it is necessary because the list of third-party hosts for hosting images or media content can be endless.

> And I cannot figure out what is the final effect of this rule, if `'self'` always overrides *, then why leave a redundant `*`.

Actually it's `*` overrides `'self'`. And yes, the `'self'` is redundant when using `*`. In large companies, IT specialists do not like to touch what works. I think that "self" just remained as an atavism after some researches, because some older Safari had a bug with `'self'`.

> I thought `nonce` is designed to prevent the usage of `unsafe-inline`, but in the above directive, both exist.

This was made for **browsers backward compatibility**.
In the presence of a CSP `nonce` the `'unsafe-inline'` will be ignored by modern browsers. Older browsers, which don't support nonces, will see `'unsafe-inline'` and allow inline scripts to execute.

Comment: You've explained very clearly. My only question was that why `*` overrides `self`, so *browsers backward compatibility* was not decided by 'order'? Or, *browsers backward compatibility* was always about `hash` & `nonce`.

Comment: (1) `*` means ANY network scheme (http:/https:/ws:/wss:/ftp:/ftps:) + ANY host_name + ANY port_number. `'self'` means scheme + nost_name + port_number from the browsers address bar + some [CSP specific magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090329/content-security-policy-and-rest-api-call-how-does-it-work/70090962#70090962).  So `*` is a broader pattern that covers all the others.

Comment: (2) decide by 'order' is not possible since browsers implement features of CSP level 1/2/3 not in order 1/2/3. Some browsers implemented CSP3 but not fully implement CSP2 features yet.

Comment: (3) browsers backward compatibility is NOT always about 'hash' & 'nonce' but in general, yes, it's about a combination of 'unsafe-inline' + 'hash' | 'nonce' + `strict-dynamic`. However, in backward compatibility, any features can be used to compensate for the lack of some features in older browsers. For example duplicating whitelist from `prefetch-src` directive into `default-src`, because Firefox does not support `prefetch-src` yet.